# Why is GLU_BGRA not found?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, opengl, bitmap

I'm building my GL application on VS2010 and the "gl.h", "glu.h" is in the Windows 7 SDK. I create mipmap with:

```
gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GLU_RGBA,Bitmap.bmWidth,Bitmap.bmHeight,
  GLU_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,Dib_Handle);
```

But VS says "GLU_RGBA" and "GLU_BGRA" not found.

OpenGL ref states that these constants are "only available if the GL version is 1.2 or greater and if the GLU version is 1.3 or greater"

Any idea how to check out why?

Comment: my bitmap is RGB inverted (red & blue swap their order)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just called [`GL_BGRA`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetTexImage.xml) rather than `GLU_BGRA`. You can use [`glGetString(GL_VERSION)`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GlGetString#glGetString.28GL_VERSION.29) to check the OpenGL version.

Comment: my VS2010 says no such thing "GL_BGRA", or my "gl.h" is out dated?

Comment: @Paul: MSVC ships with (or at least used to) *ancient* opengl header files. I'd recommend grabbing an updated version from your graphics card vendor (or [here](http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/glext.h)). It's most likely still `#define GL_BGRA_EXT                       0x80E1` in the MS opengl header file, while the new one I linked to shows `#define GL_BGRA 0x80E1`.